# How to add a single space to pad for a minus sign with ofstream using <<?

Tags: c++, padding, ofstream

I want to << floating point numbers to a file using ofstream, and include a single space when the number is positive, for example the way you would with

```
printf("% .3f",number),
```

to ensure they align. How do you format the << to include a single sign space?

Comment: Have you tried all [the standard manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)?

Comment: have you tried boost fomat library? it's just like printf, or you can use `fprintf` , `cout << boost::format("% .3f") % number;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be one already present in the standard library.
If you don't mind the verbosity, just do it the straightforward way by hand:

```
if (std::signbit(number) == false) // to avoid traps related to +0 and -0
    std::cout << " ";
std::cout << number;
```

(Don't forget to `#include <cmath>` for `signbit`!)

But this more of a "workaround".
You can also reimplement the [`num_put`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put) facet:
(this implementation is inspired by [the example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put#Example) on cppreference)

```
// a num_put facet to add a padding space for positive numbers
class sign_padding :public std::num_put<char> {
public:
    // only for float and double
    iter_type do_put(iter_type s, std::ios_base& f,
                     char_type fill, double v) const
    {
        if (std::signbit(v) == false)
            *s++ = ' ';
        return std::num_put<char>::do_put(s, f, fill, v);
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
// add the facet to std::cout
std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new sign_padding));
// now print what you want to print
std::cout << number;
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/hpie1V).
This way, you can reuse the code.

Comment: I suspected that << was not intended to have this type of formatting in std, but I thought perhaps I just didn't know about it. Thank you for the ideas!

Comment: @Machinus Actually, the approach I posted is more of intended to handle locale-specific formatting. C++ uses locales to adapt to the (very!) different cultures and customs around the world. If you are not yet familiar with them, you can read more about them -- they are a very flexible and extensible interface and worth learning. :)